# php decode function with variables

Tags: php, function, indexing, decode

E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: $realName -- at line 26   *This is the error I'm getting.

**This is my function**

```
function stats($label, $realName){
global $decode;
echo ("<p>".$label.$decode['stats']['$realName']."</p>");
};
```

**I call it like this:**

```
stats("Life: ", "life");
```

**It returns:**

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: $realName -- at line 26
Life:
```

If I change $realName to life in the actual code it will output correctly.
**Example:**
     Life: 56305

What am I doing wrong? I know it is related to how I am using $realName.

Comment: You probably want `echo ("<p>".$label.$decode['stats'][$realname']."</p>");` (remove the quotes around $realname)

Comment: @iblamefish that's what I just said; and you only removed a single single quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ("<p>".$label.$decode['stats']['$realName']."</p>");
```

Remove the single quotes around the variable:

```
echo ("<p>".$label.$decode['stats'][$realName]."</p>");
```

In single quotes variables aren't parsed.

Comment: Thank you both for helping, it solved it. I know it got closed by Gordon. I am sorry if it did not help enough people to be used. But this stumped me for a bit.  Thank you!

Comment: @user2449118 And if this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score. (you can accept after 15 mins)

Comment: I have been waiting to click it o.O